# search database SQL like query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a bookshop website with database, I need a search engine that will search the database records and present the user with results according to the keyword.

I have created the page with the text search box and search button

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Search
</h2>
<p>
    Search box.
</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding=5 bgcolor=><tr> <td align="center"> 
<asp:TextBox ID="search_box" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" Height="19px" 
    Width="75px" />
</td> 
</tr>
</table> 
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <br />
        <span id="Span1" runat="Server" style="Color:Red"></span>
    </div>
```

and this is the code behind so far

```
Partial Class Search
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SELECT * FROM BOOKS
        WHERE Title like '%"search_box.text"%'


End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why couldn't your code connect to the database and execute the query?  Do be aware of SQL injection attacks with your current line of thinking in the code though.

Comment: you need to build the html based on search result. I suggest that you have a look at some online bookstores and learn their book search patterns.

Answer (score 2):

VB.Net doesn't understand SQL... it's not as easy as just giving it a SQL Query; you need to use some type of data access layer, probably ADO.Net, and specify which SQL Server your application should connect to, how it should connect to it, etc.

I'd recommend running through a simple tutorial on connecting to SQL through VB.Net.

http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/05/vbnet-tutorial-sql-database-basics.html

-- EDIT --

Now that you're connecting to the database, it will be easiest for you to use one of the built in ASP.Net controls to display the results of your query on your web page.  The easiest way to do this will be with a "GridView" control... here's another tutorial that should get you up and running...

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22141

Comment: I followed the tutorial you suggested and this is what i have so far

Comment: 'Declare the SQLConnection
    Private Sub ConnectToSQL()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        con.ConnectionString = "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Book_id], [Category], [Title], [Description], [Quantity, [Price] FROM [Books] ORDER BY [sortfield]"
        Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While lrd.Read()
            'Do something here
        End While
    End Sub

Comment: Now i have connected to the database, how do I run search?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this...

```
Dim SearchText As String = YourTextBox.Text
Dim ds As New DataSet

Using cnn As New SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")
    cnn.Open()
    Using cmd As SqlCommand = cnn.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandType = "text"
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT* FROM BOOKS WHERE Title LIKE '{0}'", SearchText)
        Using da As New SqlDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using

SomeGridControl.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
SomeGridControl.Databind()
```

Comment: System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Conversion from string "text" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: I have replace the connection string with my own, this  is the error am getting now.